# Error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, cakephp, plupload

When I upload a picture

- File size: 375kb
- Width: 2000px
- Height: 3000px

I get an error

> ERROR
>   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 2157 bytes) in...

Why this happen, when 67108864 = 64MB?

I use a shared server. My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L] 
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L] 

</IfModule>
```

where must I write `php_value memory_limit 128M`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you only have 64M (67108864 / 1024 / 1024) allocated to PHP.

If you have access to your `php.ini`, increase the max memory size.

You can also do it in a bootstrap PHP script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Or even in your `.htaccess`

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Comment: I can upload 1 picture 2-3MB but only that picture happen error

Comment: @meotimdihia It is the dimensions of the image that are usually the problem. Are you using GD or something on it?

Comment: where i can it php_value memory_limit 128M in htaccess, see htaccess of me in post 1

Comment: @meotimdihia Just place it on a new line above the `mod_rewrite` module.