# How to avoid Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 83886080 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887692/error-allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted)

I have a (multiple) file upload form on my website, and it works, but if I upload too much files (depends on file size I guess) I get that error. I know I can edit the memory_limit property in php.ini, but is their a way I can free up that memory with php?

I'm uploading some images, then they are resized and cropped to two images, and then saved in a directory and in a database.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to free the allocated memory after use, i.e. [`imagedestroy`](http://php.net/imagedestroy).

Comment: No. It's a fundamental limit in PHP. You must have a memory_limit that excceeds the max allowed upload file size. And if you're doing image manipulation, you must have a memory limit that exceeds the raw bitmap size of the images being manipulated.

Comment: With imagedestroy I managed to clear up the memory. Thanks @Gumbo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image is no longer needed (for example when it has been copied into a different image), the memory can be freed using imagedestroy(). Here's an example:

```
function resize($width, $image,$path,$rand,$i) {
    $max_width = $width;
    $old_width = imagesx($image);
    $old_height = imagesy($image);
    $scale = ($max_width / $old_width);
    $new_width = ceil($scale*$old_width);
    $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

    imagedestroy($image);

    return imagejpeg($new,"../../../bonangana/img/albums/$path/" . $rand . "_". str_replace(" ", "_", trim($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])));
}
```