# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Tags: wordpress, memory, fatal-error

I'm fetching some information from my website e.g `category_name`, `category_id` etc. with wordpress codex and encode them with json. I'm using them in my android application but today suddenly it gave Fatal error, i cant get any data now.

error :

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45 bytes) in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1565
```

**Here are the codes (it is giving error) :**

```
 if(isset($_GET['ana_kategori'])){

$rules=array(
'parent'=>0,
);

$categories = get_categories($rules);

if($categories){

 foreach($categories as $category) {
if((($category->term_id)!=1)) {

$postsrules = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'category' => $category->cat_ID,
'post_status'=> 'publish'
);

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {

$videoimg=get_post_meta( $post->ID);
if($videoimg['small_icon']!=null) {
$videoimg=$videoimg["small_icon"];
break;
}   
}

    $output[]=array(
 'Category_Name'=>$category->name,  
 'Term_ID' => $category->term_id,
 'Image' => $videoimg[0],
 ); 
 $videoimg[0]=null;
 } // if
 } // foreach

  echo json_encode($output);

 } // first if
```

I changed the `memory_limit` in php.ini to `512M` but it didnt work. so i changed again, `8096M`, still the same. I'm using the same algorithms as it. they are working great but this is not working. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887692/error-allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted try using htaccess instead of php.ini

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm using nginx not apache i cant use htaccess :)

Comment: Then you should try with php ini itself do as like this ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: Honestly i did not understand what should i change in php.ini ? already i changed memory_limit..

Comment: Try Replace the value of Memory limit to -1 and see if you can reproduce the problem